# Battery info in notification

Tags: android

How can I make programm  which will Show Battery Life as a Percentage like notification.I created the MainActivity and Myservice.class ;

```
startService(new Intent(getApplication(), MyService.class));
```

and in MyService.class

```
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   this.registerReceiver(this.myBatteryReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

}
```

and

```
private BroadcastReceiver myBatteryReceiver
        = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        level= getString(intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0));

    }

};
```

and I tried to show it But the variable [level] =null
why and how i can get it

Comment: do you have the required permissions?

Comment: No i didn't required permission? so How?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver myBatteryReceiver
        = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       int level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);

    }

};
```